# Spring Kafka - which batch error handler to use?

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I just started to use spring-kafka 2.6.4.
I created consumer factory that polls messages by batches:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
            kafkaListenerContainerFactory(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(kafkaProperties.getTopicConcurrency());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
    return factory;
}
```

Now I want to define proper error handler that causes the consumer to stuck on the failed record and not to poll the next batch.

Which error handler should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh) is now the preferred (and default since 2.5) batch error handler. Your listener can throw a specific exception to indicate which record in the batch failed.

There is also a `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retrying-batch-eh).

Comment: Thanks, RecoveringBatchErrorHandler looks like a good idea. One more thing - if I want the consumer to stuck in an infite loop on the failed record, how can I achieve that? by setting FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS?

Comment: Just to be sure - only the partition with the failed record with get into loop, the consumer will keep polling from other partitions as usual. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct; as long as you throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` indicating which record in the batch failed. All records in the batch before that one (from any partition) will have their offsets committed. The failed record and any remaining will cause a seek operation to replay from the first unprocessed record in each partition.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, since 2.8 `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` and `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` have been deprecated in favour of `DefaultErrorHandler`.